# Warning C4691 when building a C++/CLI executable: ignore or repair?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c++-cli

When using assemblies from NuGet, I am virtually guaranteed to encounter this warning.

Our code base is mission critical.  Are these warnings going to pose a threat to our code stability and performance?  If so, how do I repair the warning condition so that instability is not an issue?

Warnings appear as follows:

```
>c:\projects\ucpro\application\ucpront\logging.h(33): warning C4691: 'System::Exception': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
>c:\projects\ucpro\application\ucpront\logging.h(33): note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Extensions::Logging::ILogger ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>c:\projects\ucpro\application\ucpront\logging.h(33): warning C4691: 'System::Func': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
>c:\projects\ucpro\application\ucpront\logging.h(33): note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Extensions::Logging::ILogger ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

An easy example is when trying to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logger. One can easily reproduce the issue with [this project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9261ina8p4gyce1/SW-132v2.zip?dl=0)

As seems to be a necessity, I am pulling the NuGet via a shim library which itself targets .NET 4.6 also, then directly pointing at the net46 folder to pull in the Microsoft.Extensions.*.dll 's.

The warnings seem like artifacts of assembly redirection from netstandard to .NET Framework

Comment: That sample project was put together with duct tape, it behaves very poorly in the IDE.  It probably works, System.Runtime will forward to mscorlib on the desktop version of the framework.  You can't get a warranty.

Comment: While I can't disagree, I challenge you to find a better way to fasten a .NET nuget to C++/CLI

Answer (score 6):

After opening an incident with Microsoft, here is the semi-canonical answer.
  Semi-canonical because

- This is paraphrasing a long conversation and
- My notes are not here, so I can't double check every detail.

Answer: Under the conditions where the project's referenced assembly is *mscorlib* but in fact the referencing class is looking for the referenced class in assembly *System.Runtime*, these warnings may be safely ignored as *System.Runtime* is (largely) to netstandard as *mscorlib* is to .NET Framework.

My own observations - not specifically coming from my incident gleanings: Under more normal (non C++/CLI) conditions, the compiler may use shim libraries to quell this error and apparently do a *minor* amount of adapter-pattern stuff as well

Comment: The warning is not completely benign. It doesn't let you debug the types defined in the netstandard library. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/55946852/9522887